# Tabbing (tabindex) targeting wrong element when new route loaded in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've got an SPA in Angular (1.4.8), using angular-route (1.4.8) and angular-material (in case that makes any difference).

Whenever a user clicks a link and is redirected to a new route, the next tab position should be the element in the ng-view with `tabindex="1"` (or 0, -1). Instead, when the new route is loaded, the next tab position is the app's logo and header menu [that appears outside the ng-view].

This creates really bad usability where user has to jump through ~5 links to target the main desired element, whenever they change a route. This especially sucks in our app because we have a form wizard that spans across several routes/views.

I think this might have started recently, maybe upon upgrade to 1.4.8 from an earlier version. Anyone have experience with this and/or suggestions on how to solve it?

Whenever ng-view renders a new route, the active tabindex position should revert to 0.

Comment: If your worry is AODA, then this probably meets the min requirement (not clearly defined to begin with) since you can still get to the new elements. You can try to manually focus on the elements but it's hard to say where the problem is without seeing this in action

Comment: Why not to create tab index directive that will add the proper attribute and remove tabindex from logo etc... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a solution found in this article on ARIA and AngularJS, which I ended up implementing: [Single page applications, AngularJS and accessibility](http://simplyaccessible.com/article/spangular-accessibility/).

```
app.run(function setupRouteChangeHandlers ($rootScope) {
  var bodyElement;

  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', setupTabIndexFocus);

  ////////////

  function setupTabIndexFocus () {
    if (!bodyElement) bodyElement = $('body');
    bodyElement.find('md-content').attr('tabIndex', -1).focus();
  }
});
```

We use angular-material so each view has an md-content element we can target (but you can target any element). When user clicks tab, the next tabindex position will be the element in the view with `tabindex="1"`.

The benefit here is we don't select the first form field, so the mobile device keyboard won't appear right away (which would cause half of the mobile device screen to be covered before the user even sees what is on the page).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set the default focus on the desired element in your form.
You may try the ['ng-autofocus'](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-autofocus) out.

Comment: There's an "md-autofocus" in angular-material, but that means the keyboard opens on mobile device the minute the page is loaded, which I think is undesirable. I ended up using the `$viewContentLoaded` method from this [Angular ARIA Guide](http://simplyaccessible.com/article/spangular-accessibility/).

Comment: Oh, and the "md-autofocus" can only be used on form fields and buttons I think, so that's why I ended up using my own solution.